# Android app crashing when I pass an intent between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, android-intent

I am trying to pass some extra data when I pass an intent to start my new activity and my app is force closing. The problem is either here

```
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Browse.this, CoffeeTypes.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("position", position);
        startActivity(myIntent);
```

Or in the next activity here.

```
      int incomingPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("position",-1);

  if(incomingPosition != -1) {
      if(incomingPosition == 0){
          Toast.makeText(this, "WEEEEEEE!0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
```

I have no idea what is causing the crash. Any ideas?

Comment: Please check and post the log, 'adb logcat'

Comment: DOH! I forgot to add my new activity to the manifest *facepalm* Thanks though, I found it through the logcat! haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not put the second class in the manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".ClassName"
  android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```